# Fetching multiple instances of LPLinkMetadata as app goes into background

Tags: ios, background-process, ios13, background-task

I have to implement this task as the app goes into the background in order to preserve the user experience, so I have to use this method instead of the new iOS 13 Background Tasks (because they may not run for a while after the app goes into the background). Fetching LPLinkMetadata instantiates a WKWebView, so Apple dictates that this must be called on the main thread. I know that this code has all sorts of code smell and I can't figure out how to fix it. And yes, I still use objective-c (it's an old app).

I am not sure if I can run this on the main thread as the app goes into the background. Is that even allowed?

My completion is wrong since the metadata for all of the links is not returned by the time it is called, but I don't know how to fix this. Threading and operations are not my strong suit yet.

I am getting terrible errors, including all of the below. I would appreciate any help or guidance.

EDIT: This is my latest code, and these are my latest errors. The errors are still almost exactly, if not exactly, the same.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    
    __block BOOL changedMetadata = NO;
    self.linkMetadataFetchers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
    self.downloadLPMetadataBgTask = [UIApplication.sharedApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"DownloadLPMetadata" expirationHandler:^{

        for (LPMetadataProvider *provider in self.linkMetadataFetchers.reverseObjectEnumerator) {
            NSLog(@"provider:%@",provider);
            [provider cancel];
            [self.linkMetadataFetchers removeObject:provider];
        }
        self.linkMetadataFetchers = nil;
        
        if (changedMetadata) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kLinkMetadataChanged object:nil];
        }
        
        [UIApplication.sharedApplication endBackgroundTask:self.downloadLPMetadataBgTask];
        self.downloadLPMetadataBgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    dispatch_group_t prepareWaitingGroup = dispatch_group_create();

    for (Link *link in _allLinks) {
        if ([Link metadataForURLString:link.linkURL] == nil) {
          
            dispatch_group_enter(prepareWaitingGroup);
            
            __block LPMetadataProvider *lpMetadataProvider = [[LPMetadataProvider alloc] init];
            
            [self.linkMetadataFetchers addObject:lpMetadataProvider];
           
            NSURL *theLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:link.linkURL];
            [lpMetadataProvider startFetchingMetadataForURL:theLinkURL completionHandler:^(LPLinkMetadata *fetchedLinkMetadata, NSError * error) {
               
                //called here because this returns on a background thread, even though called on the main thread
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    
                    [self.linkMetadataFetchers removeObject:lpMetadataProvider];
                
                    if (fetchedLinkMetadata != nil) {
                    
                        fetchedLinkMetadata.remoteVideoURL = nil;
                        fetchedLinkMetadata.videoProvider = nil;

                        [Link storeMetadata:fetchedLinkMetadata forURLString:link.linkURL];
                    
                        changedMetadata = YES;
                    }

                    dispatch_group_leave(prepareWaitingGroup);
                });
             }];
        }
    }

    dispatch_group_notify(prepareWaitingGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        
        if (changedMetadata) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kLinkMetadataChanged object:nil];
        }
        
        [UIApplication.sharedApplication endBackgroundTask:self.downloadLPMetadataBgTask];
        self.downloadLPMetadataBgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```

This error concerns me the most:

2020-06-27 20:08:42.020212-0400 MyApp 90433:1221213] [BackgroundTask] Background task still not ended after expiration handlers were called: <*UIBackgroundTaskInfo: 0x600000f87fc0>: taskID = 14, taskName = com.apple.WebKit.ProcessAssertion, creationTime = 44122 (elapsed = 45). This app will likely be terminated by the system. Call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(*:) to avoid this.

All errors:

2020-06-27 20:53:44.928496-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:44.932071-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:44.975987-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:44.977343-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:46.727973-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:46.781857-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:46.882280-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:46.931449-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:46.975164-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a30a0f0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:53:46.985055-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a1a5240 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:53:47.337484-0400 MyApp 9189:1289719] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x6000008fbbd0; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Specified target process does not exist">
2020-06-27 20:53:47.390441-0400 MyApp 9189:1289719] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x6000008dc480; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Specified target process does not exist">
2020-06-27 20:53:48.240831-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:48.282299-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:48.677632-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:48.686274-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:49.489927-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:49.576544-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:50.437313-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:50.587227-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:50.781715-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:50.828198-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:51.183576-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:51.238084-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:51.638058-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:51.685802-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:52.888413-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
2020-06-27 20:53:52.939857-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.Networking: 113: Could not find specified service
2020-06-27 20:53:53.189922-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:53.236354-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:53.337040-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:53.428921-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:53.631119-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:53.638875-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:53.690860-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:53.730806-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:55.083804-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:55.133302-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:55.483691-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a3b9e70 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:53:55.489802-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a30acc0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:53:55.838145-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:55.880263-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:55.934089-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:55.980706-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:56.034884-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:56.075052-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:56.124578-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:56.137026-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:56.232388-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:56.383354-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:56.440756-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:56.478790-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:56.727273-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a1a5000 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:53:56.738099-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a10dd80 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:53:56.831405-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:56.838785-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:56.882649-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:56.883591-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:56.928754-0400 MyApp 9189:1289719] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x6000009d2550; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Specified target process does not exist">
2020-06-27 20:53:56.934225-0400 MyApp 9189:1289719] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x6000009d29d0; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Specified target process does not exist">
2020-06-27 20:53:56.974920-0400 MyApp 9189:1289719] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x6000008aa700; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Specified target process does not exist">
2020-06-27 20:53:56.988064-0400 MyApp 9189:1289719] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x60000083a340; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Specified target process does not exist">
2020-06-27 20:53:57.339247-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:57.379947-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:57.531548-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-06-27 20:53:57.726227-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-06-27 20:53:57.783396-0400 MyApp 9189:1289719] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x6000009f0ab0; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Specified target process does not exist">
2020-06-27 20:53:57.825150-0400 MyApp 9189:1289719] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x6000009761f0; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Specified target process does not exist">
2020-06-27 20:53:58.133422-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a1a5180 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:53:58.138869-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a3b95a0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:53:58.474841-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1136dbae0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:53:58.532229-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a10d2d0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:53:58.588643-0400 MyApp 9189:1289719] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x60000090a520; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Specified target process does not exist">
2020-06-27 20:53:58.628739-0400 MyApp 9189:1289719] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x6000008d8e40; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Specified target process does not exist">
2020-06-27 20:53:58.725068-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1136db720 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:53:58.727406-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a1a5120 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:00.498097-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a1a5690 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:00.501250-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a1a56f0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:00.503221-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a30ab10 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:00.579893-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] Background task expired while holding WebKit ProcessAssertion (isMainThread? 1).
2020-06-27 20:54:01.279090-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x600003660c80>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.305336-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x600003667200>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.316119-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x60000365ac60>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.328305-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x600003666bc0>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.350447-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x60000366fd40>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.365677-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x60000366fac0>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.392971-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x6000036663a0>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.402283-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x600003669cc0>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.409426-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x60000366f3e0>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.428875-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x600003653de0>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.438579-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x6000036537a0>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.467299-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x6000036697c0>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.477215-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x60000366e3a0>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.485788-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x600003665540>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.493895-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x600003665220>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.533852-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x60000366d900>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.551979-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x600003668460>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.558096-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x600003668dc0>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.575783-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x60000366d2c0>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.582806-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x60000366d0e0>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.588045-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x600003651f40>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.636394-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x600003669040>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.655740-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] provider:<LPMetadataProvider: 0x600003650140>
2020-06-27 20:54:01.676179-0400 MyApp 9189:1289719] [BackgroundTask] Background task still not ended after expiration handlers were called: <*UIBackgroundTaskInfo: 0x600001223780>: taskID = 13, taskName = com.apple.WebKit.ProcessAssertion, creationTime = 46844 (elapsed = 42). This app will likely be terminated by the system. Call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(*:) to avoid this.
2020-06-27 20:54:01.684869-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a30ab70 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:01.690090-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a1a5390 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:01.690290-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a30a360 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:01.692242-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a1a52d0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:01.692379-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a30a5a0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:01.695908-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x113654f60 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:01.696256-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x113654d50 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:01.696387-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x113654f00 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:01.696678-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a1a52a0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:01.697827-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a1a5270 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:01.699328-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x113654fc0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:01.700580-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x113654db0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:01.701450-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a1a5210 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:01.738068-0400 MyApp 9189:1289719] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x6000008d9290; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Specified target process does not exist">
2020-06-27 20:54:01.759941-0400 MyApp 9189:1289719] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x6000008dbfc0; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Specified target process does not exist">
2020-06-27 20:54:01.769570-0400 MyApp 9189:1289719] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x6000008c14a0; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Specified target process does not exist">
2020-06-27 20:54:01.783856-0400 MyApp 9189:1289719] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x60000083ed00; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Specified target process does not exist">
2020-06-27 20:54:01.784982-0400 MyApp 9189:1289719] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x60000083e6d0; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Specified target process does not exist">
2020-06-27 20:54:01.788174-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a10d1b0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:01.832853-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a10d270 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.139156-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x113654360 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.143431-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a30a420 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.146883-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a30a480 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.156889-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a30a3c0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.167303-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a30a540 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.171760-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1136db2d0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.181832-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a30a300 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.193466-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x113654300 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.201712-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a30a4e0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.207442-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1136546c0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.214872-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1136db570 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.221105-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1136db690 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.227652-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1136db6f0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.244066-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1136db210 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.248735-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a10d0f0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.252570-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1136dbf30 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.255510-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1136db270 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.258235-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a10d210 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.260819-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1136db5d0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.263287-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a10d090 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.269637-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a10d4e0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.274536-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a10d480 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.296047-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1136dbf90 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.302052-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a10d150 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.309036-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a10df30 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.315788-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a10df90 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.322755-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a10d420 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.339500-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1136db510 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.348474-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a10dc60 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.358278-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a10dcc0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.364048-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a10dc00 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.370241-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a10d2d0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.376962-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1136543c0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.390522-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x113654660 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.397799-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x113654600 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.404010-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11a10d030 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-06-27 20:54:02.411569-0400 MyApp[9189:1289719] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1136db630 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()

Comment: Why are you fetching link meta data when your app isn't in the foreground?  This is a task that you should perform "on demand" when the user initiates some activity in your app.

Comment: Because I need to do it for previously saved links that will display in collection views throughout the app, and loading the metadata blocks the main ui. It can't be done while loading the collection view because it grinds it to a halt. It can't be done on app startup without serious delays. This is a less than ideal workaround, but still a workaround that I think will work... if I can get it to actually work. Any thoughts on if that will be possible?

Comment: Honestly it sounds like you aren’t really using LPMetaData for its intended purpose. It is a heavyweight operation that you can use to show a preview prior to sharing or taking some action.

Comment: Okay. Well, I allow users to save links within the app and I want to show a preview for each link. If I don't do it this way, then I end up having to scrape each link's site. For example, Amazon. This is illegal. So, if I don't do it this way, I can't show an image for an Amazon product. This is the best I have. I am trying to work with the tools Apple gives and within legal bounds.

Comment: I would still appreciate comment on the original problem if you have any feedback. Is it wrong to run things on the main thread in this way? Or only for this process? I just could use any helpful feedback.

Comment: Also, it will only be really used in this way the first couple of times the app runs after the next update (however long it takes to get metadata for all existing links). After that, I will do the work in the foreground as the link is created/saved. So this truly is a workaround. I just need it to work.

Comment: I can't speak from direct experience with LPMetaData but the `didEnterbackground` method is meant for lightweight work as your app transitions to being suspended. You could try calling `beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler)` to let iOS know you are performing extended work

Comment: I am using that. But the issue isn’t that I’m running on the main thread right? That part is okay?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216796/discussion-between-paulw11-and-sahm).